# Makefile: Can VPATH variable is applied to assigning Makefile variable?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, vpath

i've tried to write simple makefile for practice.

I have two directories 1. srcs(*.c), 2.include(*.h)

and try to define SRCS variable that would contain all .c files

in current directory and srcs directory.

and below is my Makefile

```
CURDIR = $(shell pwd)
OBJDIR = $(CURDIR)/objdir
VPATH = $(CURDIR)/srcs
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SRCS))

all: main

main: $(OBJS)
        gcc -o $@ $^

$(OBJS): $(SRCS) | $(OBJDIR)
        gcc -c -o $@ $<

$(OBJDIR): 
        mkdir objdir
```

I designate current/src directory as a VPATH to make find

all *.c files in current directory and current/srcs but

it cannot find *.c files in /srcs directory.

May be make cannot us VPATH when it defines the variable in Makefile

right? if it's right please let me know better approach :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VPATH` is for directories make should search to find prerequisites.

It doesn't change where `$(wildcard)` searches.

`VPATH` lets you use `foo.c` (either explicitly or implicitly) in the prerequisite list of a rule and have make look in the current directory and the `VPATH` directories for the file for it.

If you want `SRCS` to contain the `.c` files from the `srcs` directory then you need to include `srcs/*.c` in an additional `$(wildcard)` call in the `SRCS` assignment.

```
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c) $(wildcard srcs/*.c)
```